# Please Help me on C# and LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am new on C# and LINQ. I creating new website and I want to create a View form on my web. Like when people read content on my site it will update View table by 1 on my Database. I mean when people click on "read more" button it will update database.
Here is my code / I know its totally wrong/:

```
var a = from b in db.Infos
        where b.Id == Id
        select b;
var v = db.Infos.Single(g => g.Id == Id);
var c = v.Viewed;
Info medee = new Info();
medee.Viewed = c + 1;
db.Infos.InsertOnSubmit(medee);
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: please clarify your question giving more details regarding structure.   How "Read More" is connected to updating database?

Comment: Too many single letter variables, for starters (a,b, c, v, g). And the `a` is not used anywhere in your code

Comment: SWeko's above comment is **really** important, choose a name for your variables properly. It's helps us understand what you do. And most of all, it helps you understand what you do.

Comment: ty guys some1 helped me to figure it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't clear and won't do what you are requesting since `medee` is not linked to an entity that already exists, from what I understood from your code you have to do the following:

```
var a = from b in db.Infos
        where b.Id == Id
        select b;
a.Viewed += 1;
db.SubmitChanges();
```

Comment: i changed my code to   DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
        public ActionResult Index(int Id)
        {
            var a = from b in db.Infos
                    where b.Id == Id
                    select b;
            var v = db.Infos.Single(g=>g.Id == Id);
            var c = v.Viewed;
           v.Viewed += 1;
           db.SubmitChanges();
            return View(a);
        }